# Postgres remove gaps in row numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `assignment` with an `index` and `unit_id` columns. Every assignment in a unit has a unique index. This way, assignments in a unit can be reordered by swapping their indexes.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to remove potential gaps in the indexes (if a row is deleted, the indexes will go `0`, `1`, `3` for example). My current solution is to loop through each assignment in a unit programmatically and run an `UPDATE` query if its index doesn't match the loop index. Like this:

```
let i = 0;
for (const assignmentId of assignmentIds) {
  await Assignment.query()
    .patch({ index: i })
    .where('id', assignmentId);
  i++;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this with a single query using the `ROW_NUMBER` function like this:

```sql
UPDATE assignment SET
  index = subquery.new_index - 1
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as new_index 
  FROM assignment 
  WHERE assignment.unit_id = 35 
  ORDER BY assignment.index
) as subquery 
WHERE unit_id=35;
```

But when I run this, it just sets all the indexes in unit 35 to `1`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a new index for each row by identifying the rows by old index:

```
update assignment 
set index = subquery.new_index - 1
from (
    select index as old_index, row_number() over (order by index) as new_index 
    from assignment 
    where assignment.unit_id = 35 
) as subquery 
where unit_id = 35 
and old_index = index
and new_index <> old_index + 1;  -- eliminate unnecessary updates
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the subquery on the PK column (you neend you need to include that in the sub-query to be able to do that). The `order by` needs to go into the window function, not the overall query:

```
UPDATE assignment 
 SET index = subquery.new_index - 1
FROM (
  SELECT pk_column, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by unit_id order by index) as new_index 
  FROM assignment 
) as subquery 
WHERE subquery.pk_column = assignment.pk_column
```

If you only want to do that for a single unit, you can add `AND unit_id = 35` to the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the original index, you can run update with a temp sequence:

```
CREATE TEMP SEQUENCE new_index;
SELECT SETVAL('new_index', 1);
```

And run the update based on your unit:

```
UPDATE assignment SET index=nextval('new_index') WHERE unit_id=35;
```

This will update all lines on the `unit_id=35` on the `index` column.

What's the diference from your `FROM` clause? The `nextval()` executes a function for every line, returning the next number of sequence.

Comment: This won't preserve the original order defined through the existing `index` value

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically indicated unit_id was not unique ("sets all the indexes in unit 35") you can use rownum() to project the expected index for each intem (as others have indicated). But I also hate using of magic numbers, the following does not depend on them.

```
with expectations as
     (select * 
        from (
              select unit_id
                   , unit_index
                   , row_number() over (partition by unit_id order by unit_id, unit_index) exp_index
                from units
            ) au
      where unit_index != exp_index
     )
update units u
   set unit_index = exp_index
  from expectations e
 where (u.unit_id, u.unit_index) = (e.unit_id,e.unit_index);
```

See [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u2D6Fgz8nmKybbdqKMaFSN/0) here.